# How to give argument for a repeating character in snowflake regex

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My string is a comment that looks like:

```
***z|Samuel|Amount:15|Frequency:1
```

I want to use regex to filter all such rows out of a data base, my query is below

```
select 
ID,
COMMENT,
max(case when lower(COMMENT) Rlike '\*+z\|Samuel\|Amount:[0-9]+\|Frequency:[0-9]+' 
    then 1 else 0 end) as indicator
from Table_Name group by 1,2
```

But this gives me an error:

> Invalid regular expression: '*+z|Samuel|Amount:[0-9]+|Frequency:[0-9]+', no argument for repetition operator: *

Does anyone know how to navigate through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `'[*]+z[|]Samuel[|]Amount:[0-9]+[|]Frequency:[0-9]+'`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS
SELECT '***z|Samuel|Amount:15|Frequency:1' AS COMMENT;

SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE RLIKE (t.COMMENT, '[*]+z[|]Samuel[|]Amount:[0-9]+[|]Frequency:[0-9]+', 'i');
```

Output:

[image]

---

Alternatively the original `\` should be doubled or the string not wrapped with `'`:

```
 '\*+z\|Samuel\|Amount:[0-9]+\|Frequency:[0-9]+'
 =>
 '\\*+z\\|Samuel\\|Amount:[0-9]+\\|Frequency:[0-9]+'
 $$\*+z\|Samuel\|Amount:[0-9]+\|Frequency:[0-9]+$$
```

> [Matching Characters That Are Metacharacters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#matching-characters-that-are-metacharacters)
>
> If you are using the regular expression in a single-quoted string constant, you must escape the backslash with a second backslash (e.g. \., \*, \?, etc.).

```
SELECT COMMENT,
 RLIKE (t.COMMENT, '[*]+z[|]Samuel[|]Amount:[0-9]+[|]Frequency:[0-9]+', 'i') AS "[]",
 RLIKE (t.COMMENT, $$\*+z\|Samuel\|Amount:[0-9]+\|Frequency:[0-9]+$$, 'i') AS "$$",
 RLIKE (t.COMMENT, '\\*+z\\|Samuel\\|Amount:[0-9]+\\|Frequency:[0-9]+', 'i') AS "\\"
FROM t;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: marked as solved thank you, and one final question 
***z|Alphanumeric | Jhon Jones| PA | String |Date:73/65/86-58/82/03,44/79/11-26/33/60|Date:Not Valid | Arbitrary Fees|Amount:11111|Frequency:Monthly |

what if I want to ignore everything and capture rows with Arbitrary Fees

Comment: @Suyash Great to hear it. As for "Arbitrary Fees" it should be a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010946/how-to-filter-based-on-a-word-in-a-sentence-with-special-characters-regex-snowfl